# Redirect to home as a logged in user after successful registration

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a custom User model (MyUser), and a registering form (UserCreationForm) for that model. After registering the user I want it to redirect to the homepage. It is however redirecting to the homepage, but the problem is that the `user` is not logged in even after `login()` function is used in the register view, and so it is redirected back to the login page.

**views.py:**

```
@login_required(login_url='/account/login/')
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def login_view(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        user = form.login(request)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("/")# Redirect to a success page.
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form })

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("/")
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

Its giving me an error:

```
AttributeError at /account/register/
'MyUser' object has no attribute 'backend'
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please help me how to solve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, this can solve your problem.
This will authenticate and login the user after registration.

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            password = self.request.POST.get('password', None)
            authenticated = authenticate(
                username=user.username,
                password=password
            )
            if authenticated:
                login(request, authenticated)
                return redirect("/")
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Could you please help me understand why I had to login again with the authenticated and not just `login(request, user)`?

Comment: see this, maybe this clarify yours questions, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users

Comment: Great! Thank you so much.